# Lock-free flag without atomic operations

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, lock-free, rtos

I'm writing an RTOS for microcontrollers ( http://distortos.org/ ) that has to run on - amongst others - ARMv6-M architecture - which has no support for atomic operations - it has no `LDREX`/`STREX` assmebly instructions.

I'm wondering is there any clever trick that would allow me to have a very simple lock-free shared flag? Something that could be tested-and-set by only one thread until cleared. Something along these lines:

```
bool lockFreeFlag;

void serializedFunction()
{
    if (lockFreeFlag == true)
        return;

    lockFreeFlag = true;
    // initialize something
}

void anotherThread()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (lockFreeFlag == true)
        {
            // do something
            lockFreeFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this naive code when multiple threads call `serializedFunction()` then there's a race condition (thread can be preempted after the check but before setting the flag).

Maybe it's somehow possible by using two (or more) variables or an integer(s) or something else? I don't need any synchronization or waiting, the check can fail spuriously, etc. I just need to allow only one thread to enter the function until some processing is finished in which case next call to this function will succeed. I would like to avoid some "standard" forms of locking (in this case masking interrupts to disable preemption) if that would be possible. It doesn't need to be a "flag", I would actually prefer that to be a pointer, but bool, integer or something else will also be fine.

Comment: Why not use a recent C compiler which supports `stdatomics`? Or is there none?

Comment: Before ARM had `LDREX`/`STREX`, it had `SWP[B]`. You can implement a C11-style `atomic_flag` with this instruction, but more complex lock-free algorithms won't be possible.

Comment: @Olaf - if the architecture doesn't support atomic operations, then the compiler also doesn't. In such case with GCC you get linking errors about undefined functions that implement std::atomic functionality.

Comment: @EOF - ARMv6-M doesn't have SWP either...

Comment: @FreddieChopin: If you have a multiprocessor system without `LL/SC` or atomic read-modify-write operations, the manufacturer is either incompetent or malicious. You'd need a software mechanism for locking like Dekker's or Peterson's algorithm, which suck.

Comment: @FreddieChopin:You ask if this is possible. I wrote, you should first check the standard-compliant way. Just becasue if that exists, there apparently is a way. If you negate there is a way from the start, then why do you ask at all?

Comment: @EOF: ARMv6M is a (very much reduced) subset of ARMv7M. None of them has a `swp` instruction. It was designed as a direct competitor for AVR, PIC16, MSP430 and even 8051.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: The most simple (and sometimes even best) way is to `__disable_irq(); ... __enable_irq();` This is possibly even faster than the exclusive load/store approach if you have a high interrupt frequency - at the cost of slightly higher interrupt latency, of course.

Comment: @Olaf: Disabling interrupts is not a valid way to ensure mutual exclusion or atomicity on a multiprocessor system.

Comment: @EOF: Cortex-M0 systems are typically not UMA architectures in the Linux/etc. sense. Each core has its specific tasks, thus there is no concurrency between multiple such cores at application level, but through messages/signals, etc. Note that even the Cortex-M4 does not necessarily have global monitors for the `*EX`-instructions. Typically such systems communicate e.g. via a special mailbox peripheral (some HW-registers which ensure atomicity).

Comment: @Olaf - if using std::atomics would be possible, I wouldn't be asking. atomics are _NOT_ implemented in GCC for ARMv6-M, using std::atomic_flag gives stupid code (ldrb + strb), while using anything else results in linker error. Disabling interrupts in an RTOS is more complex than using these two functions - they may already be disabled and after this function they should be left in exactly the same state as before. That's why I was wondering whether there's some clever trick to do it.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Well, as this is C, a different language than C++, apparently `std::` namespace and the related syntax is not available. Anyway, my crystal ball is currently in 100 predictions service, so I cannot see what you tried and what not. 5 years after C11 has been introduced, most people still don't know about stdatomics. As you apparently are not interested in constructive hints, but concentrate on what does not work, I'll leave it at that. Just that: I have developed such systems on CPUs, some of which don't support exclusive operations. Actually they are not available on most MCUs.

Comment: @Olaf - couldn't we stick to the point? What does it matter if I'm checking `<atomic>` or `<stdatomic.h>`? With `<stdatomic.h>`, `atomic_flag` object and C-only source I get still get pointless code for ARMv6-M (`ldr` followed by `strb` and nothing more), which is exactly the same as with `<atomic>` and `std::atomic_flag`, so please - believe me that in C11 or in C++11 atomics are _NOT_ implemented for this architecture. That's why I'm not asking about use of atomic headers but for some clever programming trick (or info that there's no such thing).

Comment: It was not me to deviate from the subject. It is you constantly using C++ features for your own **[tag:c]** question. Read my last comment again and try to get my major point. You also should read [ask].